# ag-grid right click support across browsers

Tags: ag-grid, right-click

I have been looking for right click support documentation.

In what browsers it is safe to use and on what versions?

Comment: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-context-menu/ Nothing about browser support though :(